# Nvidia Cuda video encoder - output frame size

Tags: video

I am cross posting from the Nvidia forums... I got no answer there :(

I am using the Nvidia cuda video encoder nvcuvenc, and until now I was not able to encode an H.264 video with an output frame size different from the input frame size.

My question: Did anyone use this encoder with an output frame size different from the input frame size successfully?

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

More details:

The sample is the following `"C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.0\C\src\cudaEncode"` , and the encoding works fine for the default config file "704x480-h264" with the plush video.
But the other config files (720x480-h264 for example) don't work and don't seem to be correct because the input size is different than the actual video in the sample!! (I tested with other videos as well... No luck.)

To be precise: Sometimes the encoder crashes with an access violation, sometimes it encodes but the result is messed up ...

Comment: Are you quite sure you didn't do anything else wrong? – I suppose this question is better suited for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda, but you will have to provide a [short-selfcontained-compilable-example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I tested many times before posting this (i am asking for feedback to know if it's supported in the first place). Not sure if i need a SSCCE because it's a sample of the SDK so everyone who installed the Nvidia SDK should have it. Should I cross post again on cuda or delete this question totally ? Thanks